# Log4j netbeans trouble with locating/creating log file

Tags: java, logging, netbeans, log4j

I'm attempting to use log4j in Netbeans 7 on Windows 8.1.  I've placed the log4j.properties in the following location.

ProjectFolder
-src
--java

along with my application property file, that works fine.

My log4j.properties file has

```
log4j.rootCategory=, A1
# A1 is set to be a LF5Appender which outputs to a swing
# logging console. 
log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.File=c:\\logs\\example.log
log4j.appender.A1.MaxNumberOfRecords=1000
```

I've copied the log4j.jar file to my Java install C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\lib\ext and added it as a Library in project in NetBeans.

However, when I view the c:\logs folder, the file doesn't exist and I don't receive any error messages from NetBeans when it steps over the logger being called.  Also, this directory doesn't give me any problems when I use log4net and write to this directory in VisualStudio.

I've tried two or three variations of escaping the path, so I don't think that is an issue, but I'm open to suggestions.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: This could be a write permissions issue, like with this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15621520/log4j-cant-find-the-log-file . Could you try changing the path to something else, or perhaps to be a relative path in the project folder?

Comment: I originally just used log4j.appender.R.File=example.log to put it in my application folder.  That didn't seem to work either.

Comment: Solved - It seems that without a layout pattern it doesn't write anything.  Once I added log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%p %t %c - %m%n %message%newline everything worked.